# How can I dynamically add rows to a table by pressing a button?

Tags: asp.net

I want to add rows to a table control by clicking a button. I tried using the code below but getting error, can anyone please help?

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Table table = (Table)Page.FindControl("tblName");
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    tr.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
    tr.Cells[0].Text = TextBox1.Text;
    tr.Cells[1].Text = TextBox2.Text;
    tr.Cells[2].Text = TextBox3.Text;
    //add the row to the existing table.
    this.tblName.Rows.Add(tr);
    //this.tblName.Rows.Add();
}
```

--------------------asp.net-------------------------

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="btn_Click" />
    <table id="tblName" Runat="server" style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <br />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, instead of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow` you should use `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow` because your table is of type `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable`.

Anyway, your existing code is lacking some logic, as it will always add only one row, overriding what you preveiously added. To keep adding you must store what you already added somewhere, ideal place is the ViewState collection.

Optimized code would be:

```
//build array of new values
string[] currentValues = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text };

//get list from view state and append new values
List<string[]> tableRowValues = (List<string[]>)ViewState["AppendedRows"];
if (tableRowValues == null)
    tableRowValues = new List<string[]>();
tableRowValues.Add(currentValues);

//add rows to table
tableRowValues.ForEach(values =>
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow tr = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell cell = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
        cell.InnerHtml = value;
        tr.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
    this.tblName.Rows.Add(tr);
});

//update global container
ViewState["AppendedRows"] = tableRowValues;
```

Comment: @LutfunNahar it worked for me when testing locally. You should have this code inside your `btn_Click`.